# How can i make a facebox display inside a div?

Tags: jquery, facebox

I have few web pages where i use facebox, which when called appends to body and display the conntent in the middle of the page, but i need to change this setting in only one page, where the content should appear in the middle of a div and the "#facebox_overlay" div also.

Any idea how can i achieve it?

```
$(".main").append('<div id="facebox_overlay" class="facebox_hide"/>')
```

used the above code but this wont override the code written in js file which is

```
$("body").append('<div id="facebox_overlay" class="facebox_hide"></div>')
```

Comment: first `.remove` then `.append`

Comment: not working,now there's 2 div's with id="facebox_overlay"

Comment: I said `$('#facebox_overlay').remove()` then do `$(".main").append('<div id="facebox_overlay" class="facebox_hide"/>')`.You can not have elements with same `ID`

Comment: Yes!! 1st `.remove()` then `.append()`, still its not taking the remove() part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the trick, on click when the facebox opens, add following code for the click function

```
 $("body").remove('#facebox_overlay');
 $(".main").append('<div id="facebox_overlay" class="facebox_hide" />');
 $("#facebox").appendTo(".main");
```